# Wordpress remove ?id= from url

Tags: php, wordpress, query-string, permalinks

I have a page url like `www.example.com/catagory/postname`. I set up the custom permalink format as following: `/%category%/%postname%/`.

However I am still getting urls formatted like `www.example.com/category/postname/?id=123` (some number). 
I tried access directly without those and I can still access to the same page.

What should I do to get rid of the `?id=` tags following my posts URLs?

See this example link : [camilleromano.com](http://camilleromano.com)

Comment: Where do you get such urls, like admin panel (preview/view post), menu in front, inside content, archive pages?

Comment: Just visiting the site regularly would get such urls. In admin panel they are the same. I wanna clarify that ** means bold here; I removed them to prevent future confusion.

Comment: Probably some bad code is not using `get_permalink`. You need to find one of those "bad" URLs and search what template generates it. Then you'll know what piece of code is "bad".

Comment: http://camilleromano.com/  You guys can try this example. the urls for each projects are followed by ?id=2346, and strangely they are all the same.

Comment: Just to emphasise, this is a WordPress issue and should not be solved with .htaccess (I've removed the .htaccess tag). An .htaccess solution would result in an external redirect and would only mask the underlying problem.

Comment: Sure it's `%catagory%`, not `%category%` ??

Comment: Sorry for the typo here. And no, thats not the issue, they are correct in WP.